# How to generate n number of instances, with different variable names, using a for loop in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to run a simulation where a series of people are generated in a for loop and then I use them in different classes to preform certain tasks.

I'm not really sure how to generate n number of people objects while making them all accessible by the program (i.e having variable names so I can use their methods)

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez.. You shouldn't criticize newbies..

Comment: @RohitJain not criticising, just suggesting! :)

Comment: @VincenzoSanchez.. Way of suggesting doesn't look polite..

Comment: `List` is almost certainly a better idea than an array.

Comment: ArrayList specifically is probably all you need

Answer (score 2):

**-** Use `Collection` framework

**-** `Map` will be apt for this implementation.

```
Map<String,Person> personMap = HashMap<String,Person>();

personMap.put("person1",new Person("Vivek"));
personMap.put("person2",new Person("Vicky"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You generally cannot create new source code from within a running program (unless you go to byte code generation and classloaders which I do not think you have the need for here).

Instead of

```
Person a = new Person("A");
Person b = new Person("B");
a.doStuff();
b.doStuff();
```

consider having a map (untested):

```
Map<String, Person> map = new HashMap();
map.put("a", new Person("A"));
map.put("b", new Person("B"));

map.get("a").doStuff(); // on A
map.get("b").doStuff(); // on B
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array.

```
// create people
int n = 30;
Human[] human = new Human[n];    
for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
  human[i] = new Human();
}

// access specific person
human[3].doSomething();
// access all people
for (Human h:human) {
  h.doSomething();
}
```

Alternative: Use a list/set/map of persons.